# r get value only from quantile() function

Tags: r, quantile

I'm sorry for what may be a silly question.
When I do:

```
> quantile(df$column, .75) #get 3rd quartile
```

I get something like

```
75% 
1234.5
```

Is there a way to just get the value (1234.5) without the descriptive "75%" string? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can also use `unname`

```
> result <- quantile(c(1,2,3,4),0.75)
> unname(result)
[1] 3.25
```

Also you can subset by using `[[`

```
> result[[1]]
[1] 3.25
```

Comment: Or even `names(result) = NULL`

Answer (score 16):

Now you can use `names = FALSE` as argument.

```
> quantile(c(1,2,3,4),0.75, names = FALSE)
[1] 3.25
```

Answer (score 8):

Sure, you can just convert the returned value of `quantile` to a numeric. This effectively removes the names.

Illustration:

```
> quantile(c(1,2,3,4),0.75)
 75% 
3.25 
> as.numeric(quantile(c(1,2,3,4),0.75))
[1] 3.25
```

Comment: Thanks jealie! I just accepted the first answer but this works great too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`unname()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unname.html) to remove the name attribute, as in:

```r
> unname(quantile(df$column, .75))
[1] 75
```

Comment: Thanks gregor and francis! I just accepted the first answer, but I did not know about unname() as I am new to R, so thanks v much for this info. It also works perfectly